# How to set constraints on types passed through nested arrow functions (data-last style)

Tags: typescript, types, typescript-generics, arrow-functions, currying

I'm writing functionalish utilities that allow me to write code like this :

```
pipe(
  filter(propEqual("status", "STARTED")),
  takeFirst
)(exams)
```

Here are the current types :

```
export const pipe = <U>(...fns: Function[]) => (x: U) =>
  fns.reduce((v, acc) => acc(v), x);

export const filter = <T>(fn: Predicate<T>) => (collection: Array<T>) =>
  collection.filter(fn);

export const takeFirst = (collection: Array<any> = []) => 
  collection[0];
```

So far so good. I want TypeScript to detect any potential conflict with the string being passed as second argument. If someone types `"STARTEDD"` for instance, I'd like TS to say "Hey, that does not exist on Exam.

I'm trying to type the `propEqual` function and so far, this what I got :

```
export const propEqual = <T extends { [key: string]: any }, K extends keyof T>(
  key: K,
  value: T[K]
) => (item: T) => item[key] === value;
```

That compiles okay but unfortunately, that does not work. If I replace 'STARTED' by any string, the compiler does not complain.

Comment: What does what you've shown do, what does *"fails to work when used"* mean? RxJS uses piping, albeit in a slightly differnent context, seems to be hard to generalise: https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/516166ed8dc389d57bf64dd536cb845dbb23402d/src/internal/Observable.ts#L337-L429.

Comment: It means that if I replace "STARTED" by "STARTEDDD" TypeScript does not complain, although examen.statut is union type "STARTED" | "DONE". I'm trying to get TypeScript to scream at me !

Comment: You can only really get that to happen by being *very* specific - in general, I don't think TypeScript can infer the types for the pipe operators from the value that gets to passed to the function it returns (it may not get called straight away, even - `const thing = pipe(...)`).

Comment: E.g. https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgKIA84FtkG8BQyRyAzmHGAK4kBcyARAMoAqAggErOoAi9yAPgwBiASQByIxgAke9ANz4AvvnwxKIBGGAB7EMgAOwfRAA87ADTJGl5gD4AFNv0BGOvdAB9OuwCUyALy2VpZOAExunnSMfoHIzD4RIF7IvgFBzHiExFAQVFB69gBucAA2lBDeMUFhji5FpeU+PgrKquqaOnowwCWQUCZ29t290InJ8WnIAEba2iUQcCAJyO5JdMwA2gC6VXHbmcTIOXkFcFBQcACeu2cXlwB0w31DPX3NSipqGlq6BlBOqAAjpRSgMHABrCCXOiQy7aGBxSzFMoVPZgS7GeHIWE7MbrXYzOYLPQEQ7HSj5FbaKYAK121JpGxxAX8-mQyPKLU+7R+enIkKEwCgZDBq3G22WGVJ2VyFL0ng2AAYtlz8IZjCYMNhtpYtVgdWhMFgHFkntB7Pp-vogSCSvZ6GQKNR6JYmGxODxuLwmuYsvyIILhWB8D57Ps4CRDdqdvggA

Comment: At minimum filter needs a type: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgKIA84FtkG8BQyRyAzmHGAK4kBcyARAMoAqAggErOoAi9yAPgwBiASQByIxgAke9ANz4AvvnwxKIBGGAB7EMgAOwfRAA87ADTJGl5gD4AFNv0BGOvdAB9OuwCUyALy2VpZOAExunnSMfoHIzD4RIF7IvgFBzHiExFAQVFB69gBucAA2lBDeMUFhji5FpeU+PgrKquqaOnowwCWQUCZ29t290InJ8WnIAEba2iUQcCAJyO5JdMwA2gC6VXHbmcTIOXkFcFBQcACeu2cXlwB0w31DPX3NSipqGlq6BlBOqAAjpRSgMHABrCCXOiQy7aGBxSzFMoVPZgS7GeHIWE7MbrXYzOYLPQEQ7HSj5FbaKYAK121JpGxxAX8-mQyPKLU+7R+enIkKEwCgZDBq3G22WGVJ2VyFL0ng2AAYtlz8IZjPYsk9oCYMNgHPp-vogSCSvZ6GQKNR6JYmGxODxuLwmuYsvyIILhWB8D57BL8EA

Comment: Man it works!! Brilliant, all i had to do was pass an explicit type in the filter, which is totally acceptable to me. Its even better, because it helps documenting what type is getting out at each stage of the process. Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

I would give `propEqual` typings like this:

```
const propEqual = <K extends PropertyKey, V>(
  key: K,
  value: V
) => (item: Record<K, V>) => item[key] === value;
```

Note that `PropertyKey` is just `string | number | symbol`.  The idea is that when you call `propEqual` you have no idea what type `item` will be; the compiler can only reliably infer types of values you actually have and not ones you will get later.  So given `key` and `value` you can infer `K` and `V`.  With that, the returned function will need to accept an item of type `Record<K, V>` (see [doc](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeystype)), meaning an item with a property at key `K` of type `V`.

Depending on your use case, you may need something less specific than `Record<K, T>`.  If the thing you're testing has a value at key `K` that is not the same as `V` but wider, you want to accept that too.  So you only want to verify that `item` is of type `T` where `T[K]` and `V` have overlap (that is, `T[K] & V` is not `never`).  So possibly this:

```
const propEqual2 = <K extends PropertyKey, V>(
  key: K,
  value: V
) => <T extends Record<K, T[K] & V extends never ? V : T[K]>>(item: T) => (
  item as Record<K, V>
)[key] === value;
```

---

Examples.  Let's imagine we have an `Item` interface:

```
interface Item {
  status: "STARTED" | "IN PROGRESS" | "ENDED",
  title: string
}
declare const item: Item;
```

Then you can see both `propEqual` and `propEqual2` work to accept/reject things where `Item` has/doesn't have a value of the specific type inferred:

```
propEqual("title", "hello")(item); // okay
propEqual("title", 123)(item); // error! string is not assignable to number
// -------------------> ~~~~
propEqual2("title", "hello")(item); // okay
propEqual2("title", 123)(item); // error! string is not assignable to number
// --------------------> ~~~~
```

If you call `propEqual("status", "STARTED")`, the `V` type will be inferred as `string`.  That's too wide for your test, so you'll need to write something like `"STARTED" as const`, for example, since a [`const` assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions) will cause `V` to be inferred as the narrower [string literal type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/literal-types.html#string-literal-types).  There are other ways around this but they are annoying (see [microsoft/TypeScript#30680](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30680)).

Anyway:

```
propEqual("status", "STARTED" as const)(item); // error 
// "IN PROGRESS" not assignable to "STARTED"
```

You can't use `propEqual` for this because `item`'s `status` property is *wider* than `"STARTED"`.  We'll need `propEqual2`:

```
propEqual2("status", "STARTED" as const)(item); // okay
```

And now if you misspell `STARTED` you can get the warning you're looking for:

```
propEqual2("status", "STARTEDD" as const)(item); // error again
// -------------------------------------> ~~~~
//  Type '"STARTED" | "IN PROGRESS" | "ENDED"' is not assignable to type '"STARTEDD"
```

---

Now, whether or not this actually helps in your use case depends strongly on the type signatures of your `pipe`, `filter` and `takeFirst` functions.  You haven't included these, so I consider them out of scope for this question.  But I've seen this kind of thing fail before, so I wouldn't be surprised if you run into additional issues.  Hopefully this helps you get started though.

---

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-Msl82sS2JKUyuUCAFKlVql1anXZo0myuxCU162y20CB3OzXuN3Zz07X30pnBlNhjYQSPRuMJpMptMZhBZg1Fvd70vl8IW3tS76-CDy4FgiFkxcwPlQVtj9sehBexEotFYnF42Gh8MlyjGN4yeddr3BSEYW7cV4gSM8oB+P4rxBSC702B9wGgZ8zHHA1O04Y8q17eCAXPZCG1Q28oRhe9HxwvCKHfHYNkZLArh3XN924njuMPMtOI6Tg2BgAByCDqIJT9USYDFsVxfF4URYlSRhUS5wAxdlxAtdky4ETxKoqCYSAA)

Comment: Thank you for a comprehensive answer and many links. Unfortunately, it does not seem to work on my code, but since I now have a working albeit not ideal solution, I'll use this one.

Answer (score 0):

So, the trick consists of giving an explicit type to the `filter` function. This works :

```
pipe<Examen[]>(
  filter<Examen>(propEqual("statut", "PROGRAMME")),
  filter<Examen>(propEqual("categoriePermis", mandat.categoriePermis)),
  filter<Examen>(or(prévuAujourdhui, prévuDemainMaisTropTardPourAnnulerAujourdhui)),
  takeFirst
)(examens);
```

Awesome ! FP expressiveness & type safety, in JS. Who needs Haskell really ahah !